# Auto-layout and transforms not working together for UIViewController transition

Tags: animation, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, transform

I have a UIViewController being presented with a UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning object to do the animation. The animation has a collection view cell expand and fade out as the new view controller's view fades in, expanding in the same way. So it looks like you have an expanding cell that transforms into the new view controller. But weirdly enough, the subviews of the cell get transformed in weird ways when they use auto-layout. When I don't use auto-layout, this doesn't happen. What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your cell to `[[transitionContext containerView] superview]` in `- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext`, instead of `[transitionContext containerView]`

For some reason this worked for me